# Como hacer smooth scroll desde un span que está en una animación?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

```js
$('.goto').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 1000);
});

function list_shuffle_texts() {
  var count_shuffle_texts = 0;
  var current_shuffle_text = new Array();
  $('.shuffle-texts span').each(function(){
   var current_shuffle_element = $(this);
   count_shuffle_texts++;
   current_shuffle_text[count_shuffle_texts] = current_shuffle_element.html();
  });
  $('.shuffle-texts').before('<p class="shuffle-texts-container"></p>');
  $('.shuffle-texts').hide();
  var current_shuffle_no = 0;
  $('.shuffle-texts-container').hide();
  function show_shuffle_texts() {
   current_shuffle_no++;
   if (current_shuffle_no > count_shuffle_texts) current_shuffle_no = 1;
   $('.shuffle-texts-container').fadeIn(500).shuffleLetters({
    'text' : current_shuffle_text[current_shuffle_no]
   });
   setTimeout(function() {
    $('.shuffle-texts-container').fadeOut(500, show_shuffle_texts);
   }, 4000);
  }
  show_shuffle_texts();
 }

 function list_fading_texts() {
  var count_fading_texts = 0;
  var current_fading_text = new Array();
  $('.fading-texts span').each(function(){
   var current_fading_element = $(this);
   count_fading_texts++;
   current_fading_text[count_fading_texts] = current_fading_element.html();
  });
  $('.fading-texts').before('<p class="fading-texts-container"></p>');
  $('.fading-texts').hide();
  var current_fading_no = 0;
  $('.fading-texts-container').css({'opacity' : '0'});
  function show_fading_texts() {
   current_fading_no++;
   if (current_fading_no > count_fading_texts) current_fading_no = 1;
   $('.fading-texts-container').html(current_fading_text[current_fading_no]).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
   setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fading-texts-container').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, show_fading_texts);
   }, 3000);
  }
  show_fading_texts();
 }





 $(window).load(function() {
  list_fading_texts();
  list_shuffle_texts();

  });
```

```css
#1 
{
width:800px;
height: 500px;
}

#contacto 
{
width:800px;
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Shuffle/4.2.0/shuffle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<article id="shufle">
  <div class="container">
   
  
  <p class="fading-texts text-center">
   <span>jkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj</span> 
   <span>kljlkjlkjlkjljljljlj </span>
   <span>kljlkjlkjlkjlkj </span>
   <!-- <span>y me gusta el café</span> -->
   <span>¿ lkjklj  <a class="goto" href="#contacto">lkjljj</a></span>
  </p>
 
  <p class="read-on">
   <a href="#about" class="goto">
   <span class="goDown">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-cog-white"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="htxt">Read on </span>
   </a>
  </p>
 </div>
</article>
<article id="1">
<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
</article>
<article id="contacto">
<h1>contacto</h1>
</article>
```

Quiero hacer un scroll de un segundo desde un enlace que esta en una animación de texto. Y no lo consigo. desde el menú y desde un icono de flecha si me funciona el siguiente código:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 1000);
});


$('.goto').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

Pero desde la animación no me funciona. 
Esta es la animación:

```
<p class="fading-texts text-center">
            <span>gdfgdfgfdgdfg</span>  
            <span>gfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg </span>
            <span>fdgdfgdfgdfg </span>
            <span>¿ Necesitas una web ?  <a class="goto" href="#contact">contactame</a></span>
        </p>
    <p class="read-on">
            <a href="#about" class="goto">
            <span class="goDown">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-cog-white"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="htxt">Read on </span>
            </a>
        </p>
```

los span van saliendo y ocultandose. ¿ Es por esto por que el enlace no esta en el DOM del html o????

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve]. No está muy claro a lo que te refieres con que el span está en una animación o que es lo que está fallando

Comment: alvaro ya he puesto un ejemplo

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeIn(...).shuffleLetters is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 75,
  "colno": 46
}

Comment: si ya vi ese error pero la animacion funciona. que tiene que ver con el otro codigo que hace el scroll?